# Google Map not displayed

Tags: google-maps

I'm setting up a website and I'm using Avada Theme. I'm using avada's builder to insert a Google Map but it won't show. I get this:

[image]

Does anybody know what's going wrong?

Comment: Is this when using a new API key? Or have you restricted the API key to a specific domain? Is it working now?

Comment: Ok, did it. I didn't know about the API key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be that you haven't set your Google Maps API key. Or, if you have already set an API key then it might be due to any restrictions that you may have set for the API key such as restricting it to a specific domain.

You can obtain a Google Maps API key from here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key